# Name of the song that plays in episode 6 and 21?

Tags: music, code-geass

What is the name of the song that plays in Code Geass R1 during episode 6 around 12:20 and in episode 21 around 13:02? Where can I obtain this song?

Answer (score 1):

> episode 6 around 12:20

The title is **School Festival!**

> episode 21 around 13:02

The title is **Alone**, sung by Hitomi.

> Where can I obtain this song?

Well both song included in *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion Original Soundtrack 2*, you can purchase the copy in some online store, such as [this one in Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000N3SXVM). Or if you mean where you can hear it online, hard to decide the legality of the source, so I don't think it can be put here.